# Download Google Plus user CoverPhoto

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I see in the google plus documentation that [users have cover photos.](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/model/people/Person.Cover)

So here's a gist of how I build an api client with what I feel are sufficient privileges and get the current person's cover photo along with other information.

```
private static final String SCOPE_EMAIL =
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read";

private GoogleApiClient buildGoogleApiClient() {
    return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
        .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
        .addScope(new Scope(SCOPE_EMAIL))
        .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE).build();
}

private User createUserFromGoogle() {
    _googleApiClient = buildGoogleApiClient();

    Person currentUser = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(_googleApiClient);
    String userUID = GOOGLE_UID_PREFIX + currentUser.getId();
    String firstName = currentUser.getName().getGivenName();
    String lastName = currentUser.getName().getFamilyName();
    String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(_googleApiClient);
    String profileURL = getLargeImageURL(currentUser);
    Person.Cover cover = currentUser.getCover();
    String coverURL = null;
    Timber.e("has cover:" + currentUser.hasCover());
    if (cover != null) {
        CoverPhoto coverPhoto = cover.getCoverPhoto();
        if (coverPhoto != null) {
            coverURL = coverPhoto.getUrl();
        }
    }
    //Create a new {@link User} with empty groups, contacts, and channels
    Id id = Id.builder().value(userUID).build();
    return User.create(id, firstName, lastName, email, profileURL, coverURL, null, null, null);
}
```

`createUserFromGoogle()` is called after authenticating with google plus sign in when we are "connected" in the `ConnectionCallbacks`. Each time, `hasCover()` always returns false, and `Cover` is always null. Has anyone successfully downloaded a coverPhoto URL? All other information is retrieved successfully.